# Coordinate two range inputs based on an array of levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range, increment

I have an app in which two 'sliders' (HTML range inputs) interact with each other, updating one updates the other.  I am trying to wrap my head around the best high-level approach to what I need to do.  Originally, the sliders were updated on a consistent integer of '16'. For example:

**Range 1**

```
<input id="range-2" type='range' min='1' max='7' step='1' />
```

**Range 2**

```
<input type='range' min='0' max='96'  step='16' id="range-3" />
```

Initially, updating the increment of either slider was directly correlated in terms of steps.  For example, updating the first slider from '1' to '4' would take the second slider 3 steps up as well, from 0 to 48.  Now the client wants different values based on what step the user is currently on.  For example, changing `slider 1` from '1' to '2', will take `slider 2` from '0' to '4', but changing `slider 1` from '2' to '3' will take `slider 2` from '8' to '16'.  Basically, there is no longer a constant.  I am just wondering what the best high-level approach to this is.

The new values are as follows with the left column showing changes in `slider 1` and the increment that would update `slider 2`:

```
1 to 2 => 4
2 to 3 => 8
3 to 4 => 16
4 to 5 => 16
5 to 6 => 24
6 to 7 => 12
```

My new **Range 2** would look something like:

```
<input type='range' min='0' max='80'  step='4' id="range-3" />
```

Anyone have any starting ideas for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many different ways of doing that. One possibility is to pre-compute the correspondence tables between the two ranges.

```js
var slider = [
      document.getElementById('range-1'),
      document.getElementById('range-2')
    ],
    fromSlider = [ [], [] ];

function initSliderTables(step) {
  var p = 0;

  step.concat(0).forEach(function(s, i) {
    for(var j = 0; j <= s; j++) {
      fromSlider[1][p + j] = i + 1;
    }
    fromSlider[0][i + 1] = p;
    p += s;
  });
}

function update(from) {
  slider[from ^ 1].value = fromSlider[from][slider[from].value];
  
  document.getElementById('debug0').innerHTML = slider[0].value;
  document.getElementById('debug1').innerHTML = slider[1].value;
}

initSliderTables([ 4, 8, 16, 16, 24, 12 ]);
update(0);
```

```html
<input id="range-1" type='range' onchange="update(0)" min='1' max='7' step='1' />
<span id="debug0"></span><br>
<input id="range-2" type='range' onchange="update(1)" min='0' max='80' step='4' />
<span id="debug1"></span>
```

We can avoid the `for` loop by doing:

```
step.concat(1).forEach(function(s, i) {
  fromSlider[1] = fromSlider[1].concat(Array(s).fill(i + 1));
  fromSlider[0][i + 1] = p;
  p += s;
});
```

However, `.fill()` is not yet supported by all browsers.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please note that I published for a few minutes an edited version which was not compatible with IE. I since rolled back and added the alternate code as a foot note. Make sure to use the one that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way could be to define an array with increments and use it to define range settings; in this sample I write a simple increment because I didn't understand what your exact needs, but this is the idea, then you can simply change the operation on 'change' event.

```
var increments = [0,4,8,16,16,24,12];

$('#range-3').attr('max', increments.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
$('#range-3').attr('step', Math.min.apply(null,increments.slice(1,increments.length)));

$('#range-2').on('change', function() {
    $('#range-3').val($('#range-2').val() + increments[$(this).val()-1]);
});
```

[Here a sample jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/wL0gxxp7/)